# Pseudo a:hover & a:hover:before at the same time using only CSS

Tags: css

How to fix this problem at the same time correctly?
Thanks!

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/c4xrfLv5/]
```

Comment: Sore about https://jsfiddle.net/c4xrfLv5/

Comment: you should add `transition` into your `figure.button a:before` so that it work perfect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would do the job:

```css
figure.button figcaption {
  position: relative;

}
figure.button a {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  padding: 0px 25px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  background-color: #79A70A;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 2s;
}

figure.button a:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width:  0 0 40px 30px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #79A70A;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  transition: 2s;
}
figure.button a:hover {
  background-color: #858500;
}

figure.button a:hover:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #858500;
}
```

```html
<figure class="button">
<br><br><br><br>
<figcaption>
<a href="#">Read More</a>
</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Also make sure you using `:after` instead of `:before` because your triangle shape is after the element ;-), just to make it correct!

Comment: Good job putting it in a snippet.

Comment: Ou, thanks!
I hope so this example with that border-width style will work fine in all modern browsers... Actually I have no idea :)

Comment: On that case you could also use css shaping, its for the after pseudo:

#triangle-topleft {
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-top: 100px solid red;
 border-right: 100px solid transparent;
}